# css html curved header

Tags: html, css, header, curve, css-shapes

I am wondering if anyone can point me in the right direction/or the best method of placing the following image as a header.  I am not a web programmer so i am winging this.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8385g42806yisv/man-with-flag.png?dl=0

not sure, if the image should be slices in two, to make one rectangle and the other the one with the curve

or make the image rectangular, and apply CSS

there will be three section below the image, so idealy  the section below should transition seamlessly.

Comment: As long as the empty parts of the image are transparent, then you can set it as the background image of a header and it'll work fine. :)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/chipChocolate/woeh48pw/

Comment: That was what i had assumed,  however my sections from after the image do not go underneath.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/hj5uwsxojv7cepl/manflag.png?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Similar to this http://jsfiddle.net/lotusgodkk/7fjSc/1006/ ?

**CSS:**

```
.a {
    position: relative;
    height: 70px;
    width: 600px;
    background: #182F5B;
}
.a:before, .a:after {
    content:"";
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 100% 50%;
}
.a:before {
    width: 340px;
    height: 80px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    right: -5px;
    top: 40px;
}
.a:after {
    width: 300px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: #182F5B;
    left: 0;
    top: 27px;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div class="a" /><div/>
```